# How to push a json array as a record into csv using node js

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, csv

I am trying to convert a json array into a CSV by using node js jsonexport module. The json looks like

```
[
{
"value": [
  {
    "id": "178",
    "name": "Mark"
  },
  {
    "id": "549",
    "name": "Brendan"
  },
  {
    "id": "101",
    "name": "Terminal"
  }
]},
{
"Feed_id": "997"
}
]
```

when i do a json to csv export to the above json, my csv file looks like:

```
value.id   value.name   Feed_id
178        Mark        
549        Brendan
101        Terminal
                        997
```

how to write a CSV file with Feed_id as a column with object value and Value as a another column name with the array as the value for it as following

```
Feed_id           value
997             [{"id":"178","name":"Mark"},{"id":"549","name":"Brendan"},{"id":"101","name":"Terminal"}]
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
var data = [{
    "value": [{
        "id": "178",
        "name": "Mark"
      },
      {
        "id": "549",
        "name": "Brendan"
      },
      {
        "id": "101",
        "name": "Terminal"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Feed_id": "997"
  }
];

var result = Object.assign.apply(null, [{}].concat(data));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. But i am still having the same issue when i convert the array into CSV. I want to store the array "value" as an array inside the csv file for the feed_id:997

Comment: Could you please pretty print your expected array in your post?

Comment: I need a CSV file with an array value as a record.

Comment: When i am tring to convert json to csv, the jsonto csv export converts each header and key value as column name. For example value.id becomes a column name in the csv.

Comment: If you are using a 3rd party tool to export data to CSV, you will not be able to achieve what you want as those converters are designed to iterate through those objects.

Comment: have you got any idea to achieve this?

Comment: I guess you have to write your own functionality. As I told you, all 3rd party csv tools iterate through your arrays. So you wont have an array in the result.